# Edit a post in mobile web immediately displays suggested tags

Tags: bug, tags, mobile-web, editor

Post editor in mobile web immediately displays suggested tags which names contain a substring of the first already set tag:

> [image: bug-tag]

On MSE it only happens with questions tagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). On another sites there are more cases, e.g. on ruSO with [c++] tag:

> [image: c++-tag]

Tapping on suggested tag replaces first of already existed.