# On which sites are suggested tags currently enabled?

Tags: support, tags, suggested-tags

There is a feature called [suggested tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206907/how-are-suggested-tags-chosen) where the software suggests some additional tags depending on what is already written.

Originally I thought that they are only enabled on Stack Overflow, SO meta has [several posts tagged (suggested-tags)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/suggested-tags).

But then I noticed that:

- Probably they are also on language variations of SO, judging by the screenshot shown here: [Edit a post in mobile web immediately displays suggested tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296237).
- This post mentions that they are also enabled on Meta Stack Exchange: [Enable suggested tags on other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320163). And I was offered suggested tags also when I was going to choose the tags for this post.
- The tag (suggested tags) exists also on [Ask Ubuntu meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/suggested-tags).
- I have now found a question showing a screenshot with suggested tags [on Ask Different Meta](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3701).

**Question:** On which sites are suggested tags enabled?

---

Here is a screenshot showing suggested tags which I was shown when writing this question. (Although I am not really sure *when* they appeared - whether it was only after the body was long enough.)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Only sites with [20k+ questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212310/323179) should be eligible for it, though it’s not enabled on all sites with well more than 20k questions.

Comment: @Laurel Is there an easy way to test whether some specific site has this feature request enabled? For example here on [meta.se] when I try to write a question (without actually submitting it), sometimes I am shown the suggested tags and sometimes not. A while ago I have tried the same on [so], and I did not get any suggested tags. So I do not know how I would *reliably* test whether it is enabled on some specific site.

Comment: I’m not sure. Could it be that you only get suggestions when the system is fairly certain of what tags you should use? (When searching I found that both Math and MathOverflow had requests for the feature, which is how I know it’s not automatically enabled on all large sites.)

Comment: This [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320166/282094) says it takes 20K questions to train, looking at the [site list (in number of questions order)](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions) shows Math.SE has 1.4M questions/20K= **70+** tags. [Math.meta.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28060/510296) does have an unanswered Feature Request. SuperUser has 456K/20K=23 tags, and [doesn't appear to](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/suggested-tags) have a Feature Request. Perhaps the answer is "only SO"; because it's the only place that *could* have helpful suggestions.

Comment: @Laurel The feature requests [on MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3652) and [on Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28060) were posted by me. I would hope that somebody would point it out, if I am requesting something which already works and I have simply missed it.

Comment: @Rob Based on the [screenshot in this post](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3701) it seems that it is enabled on [apple.se]. (Or at least that it was enabled at the time when that question was posted.)

Comment: Martin, it ***can*** be enabled, but how well it works. Here is an [AD.meta.SE Q&A](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3702/317593) complaining about bad results. --- I understand that your question is: "where is it enabled?" but [your comment asks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359591/on-which-sites-are-suggested-tags-currently-enabled?noredirect=1#comment1200221_359591): "where does it 'work'?", AD.SE has 5.6*average#tags (3?), so 17 *good* suggested tags; and edge cases not so helpful. --- Still, not a dupe, there's no list; I just think that the answer will be short.

Comment: @Rob I apologize for being imprecise. I should have written "something which already is enabled" in that comment.

Comment: Since posts on various per-site-metas have been linked in the comment, I will add a link to a [post on Biblical Hermeneutics Meta](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3716#3717) - the conclusion there was that the site doesn't have enough questions for this.