# On the sites where suggested tags are enabled, were they actually useful?

Tags: discussion, statistics, suggested-tags

What is the experience with the "suggested tags" feature on the sites which actually use it? Did it help in some way?

I understand that this is something which is difficult to quantify in some reasonable way - but users from those sites might be able to say about their experience. (And maybe something like this might have been discussed on a per-site-meta.)

---

At least for a new user, choosing the tags for their question is not a straightforward task - familiarity with the site and with the tag systems definitely helps, but it takes time to learn about those things. There are various ways in which both the software and the community around the site tries to help askers to tag their questions correctly.

There are a few sites which use [suggested tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/suggested-tags/info). (I do not know the complete list, but some such sites are mentioned in this question: [On which sites are suggested tags currently enabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359591))

When enabling this feature on another site is discussed, it definitely helps to know whether whether it worked satisfactorily on other sites

If you have some experience with this feature, I'd be grateful for any input. And links to some discussions on per-site-metas are welcome, too.

For example, I have seen a post on Meta Stack Overflow mentioning that this feature might suggest tags in a way which contradicts the usage of tags agreed by the community on that site: [Incorrect tag suggestions when posting a C or C++ question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408977).  I see that there are [40k questions tagged with both tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%20c%2b%2b) - I am not familiar enough with tags on SO to be able to tell whether or not among those questions some are tagged incorrectly.

Naturally, the feature is limited by the sample on which it was trained. On sites where I am relatively active (and more familiar with their tags), I know that some tags are often used incorrectly - and not all mistagged questions are fixed by more experienced users. (And there are even tags where there isn't a clear consensus on how they should be used.) So for questions related to those tags I'd expect that the algorithm trained on the questions posted on the site would return less than optimal results.